html to pdf converter, download in dart and flutter
I am creating a web application. I have one page where I preview my HTML content. I use webview widget since html viewer doesn't recognize completely HTML styling.
I need to have a button that could download a pdf file. Pdf file needs to be that html.
Can someone give me an example code, please? I have tried a lot of stuff from internet, but nothing works for me or web.
Using some dependencies from pub.dev. But either they are not compatible with web, or I don't have a proper option to load html.

Seems this exists, which is what you're likely looking for. StackOverflow is meant to be for resolving problems or answering programming queries, not for us to engineer an entire feature for your website. I'd say you should take a look at the flutter_html_to_pdf and the example.

It is not compatible with web version. I don't need anyone to engineer an entire feature. Just to give me an example of dependency that can work properly.
